# Remove %20 from urls

Tags: python, django, django-urls

My urls in django have `%...`. How can I change that? At first this was ok but suddenly changed at some point in my day. My views, models and urls are as follow:

```py
class Rant(UUIDModel, TitleSlugDescriptionModel, TimeStampedModel, models.Model):
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)

    def slugify_function(self, content):
        return content.replace("_", "-").lower()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("rants:rant-detail", kwargs={"title": self.title})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

```py
class RantDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Rant
    slug_field = "slug"
    slug_url_kwarg = "slug"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

````py
    path("<str:slug>/", RantDetailView.as_view(), name="rant-detail"),
    path("category/<slug:category>/", rant_category, name="rant-categories"),```

I have no Idea why the link on my localhost is `localhost:8000/first%20rant%20on%20rantr/`

Does anyone know where I made a mistake? I'm expecting the urls to have `hyphens` in it like `http://localhost:8000/first-rant-on-rantr/` where did I make a mistake?
````

Comment: `%20` means _space_. Your "slugs" are not real [slugs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/glossary/#term-slug) and contain characters that must be escaped. And they get escaped that's why you see %20 where were spaces. Fix your slugify function and update data in DB.

Answer (score 1):

#### Improve your `slugify` function like this:

```
    def slugify_function(self, content):
        return content.replace("_", "-").replace(" ","-").replace("%20","-").lower()
```

#### A full library function is even better

It covers a wider variety of odd characters that you might come across occasionally.

```
from django.utils.text import slugify
```

Comment: It's still coming out with %20

Comment: When I type in `localhost:8000/first-rant-on-rantr/` I get the error ```No rant found matching the query
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/first-rant-on-rantr/
Raised by: rantr.rants.views.RantDetailView```